# How to show first data in a series in a line chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a line chart with years and months.

In my newest line (2021) I have just 1 column of data in the series. In this case Excel doesn't show anything.

|  | jan | feb | mar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | 5 | 5 | 6 |
| 2020 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| 2021 | 9 |  |  |

In this case I achieve this chart:

[image: Line chart]

As you can see my 2021 january data does not plot.

I've tried every option in "hidden and empty cells" (sorry,I'm using other language, bu I sure you know the option I'm talking about)

What I'm looking for is a way to achieve something that looks like this mockup I did in paint:

[image: Paint mode chart]

Comment: I would love to achieve this without using bogus data in upcoming months.

Comment: By definition, a line is the distance between two points. If there is only one point, there cannot be a line. So, think outside the box of lines.

Comment: @teylyn You're correct. Maybe I should use bars instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your chart type from LINE to LINE WITH MARKERS (4th one over in line chart design).

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I thought this would be an option in the line chart instead of a different chart type.